# Error while installing numpy in Pycharm & Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, numpy

I am a novice who started taking lessons from udemy for learning Python. I did a take a small course on datacamp.com and it was going good. Today I encountered this error when I tried to install numpy in pycharm ( as follows ). I upgraded Python to 3.6.2. I also uninstalled and reinstalled numpy but nothing works. I am not an engineer by background. Maybe there is a solution on this website which i read but still did not understand. I request you to explain it in simpler ways. I will really really appreciate it.  This is the error in Jupyter Notebook

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>()
     15 try:
---> 16     from . import multiarray
     17 except ImportError as exc:

ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fa44af558781> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd

C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>()
    140         return loader(*packages, **options)
    141 
--> 142     from . import add_newdocs
    143     __all__ = ['add_newdocs',
    144                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',

C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15 ###############################################################################

C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py in <module>()
      6 from numpy.version import version as __version__
      7 
----> 8 from .type_check import *
      9 from .index_tricks import *
     10 from .function_base import *

C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py in <module>()
      9            'common_type']
     10 
---> 11 import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
     12 from numpy.core.numeric import asarray, asanyarray, array, isnan, zeros
     13 from .ufunclike import isneginf, isposinf

C:\Users\rahul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>()
     24 Original error was: %s
     25 """ % (exc,)
---> 26     raise ImportError(msg)
     27 
     28 for envkey in env_added:

ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```